# The exception "NoSuchMethodError" appears in a multi module project of maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, exception, nosuchmethoderror

I'm developing a client server application. For that matter I created a maven project "mydbapp" which consists of the sub modules: core, client, server. In the core project I placed java source files which both the server and the client have in common. These classes are only initialized either in the client or server project. If I press the run button in eclipse while in the client project, I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void blue.macrolab.mydbapp.utils.MyLogger.(blue.macrolab.mydbapp.model.AbstractModel, java.lang.String)'
> at blue.macrolab.mydbapp.model.AbstractModel.setLogger(AbstractModel.java:142)
> at blue.macrolab.mydbapp.model.Model.(Model.java:24)
> at blue.macrolab.mydbapp.App.start(App.java:40)

In the client project a created a class called Model.java which inherits the methods and attributes from the abstract class "AbstractModel.java" located in the core project. But the setLogger Method in the abstract Class "AbstractModel.java" exists and is implemented as follows:

```
public void setLogger(AbstractModel data) {
this.myLogger = new MyLogger(data,this.fs.getFolder()+ConstantsSettings.SLASH+this.fs.getLogFolder()+ConstantsSettings.SLASH+this.fs.getLog());
}
```

The class "MyLogger.java" is located in the core project but initalized in the client and server projects.
I also compiled the core project using maven which created a jar file. The core's pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>blue.macrolab.mydbapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myDbApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>blue.macrolab.mydbapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>core</name>

  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <!--  <scope>test</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
      <version>3.16.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
      <version>3.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
      <version>3.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
   <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
  </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.9.0</version>
                 <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.2.2</version>
                  <configuration>
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>  
                        <mainClass>blue.macroLab.spectrometer.App</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>
                  </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The parent's pom.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>blue.macrolab.mydbapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>myDbApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>myDbApp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>client</module>
    <module>server</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

[image: App.java in core project]

[image: App.java in client project]
[image: libraries in client]

Comment: Is the core dependency defined in your client and server poms?

Comment: The long and the short of it is that you are compiling against one version of a class, and executing against another that doesn't have the method

Comment: To get rid of it, you need to clean (ie delete) your existing classes/jars you've created and rebuild the dependency class